# Why didn't a design appear under Thor & Loki when teleported?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers, thor

Whenever Thor goes from place to place magically a strange design appears in the ground under him. But in *The Avengers*, Thor & Loki went to Asgard. But no design appeared under them? Why didn't it happen?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because they used Tesseract/Space stone's powers:

Both rotate the handle of Tesseract case and teleported with blue light.

Also we already know biforst was not in working condition during the film events:

> **LOKI:** Oh, you should thank me. With the Bifrost gone how much dark energy did the Allfather have to muster to conjure you here? Your
>   precious Earth. - [source](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Avengers,-The-(2012).html)

Comment: It would be helpful to add that normally, they use the Bifrost to "teleport", which is what adds the "design" (by whatever mechanism; wasn't it mentioned in the original Thor that it has something to do with targeting?).

Comment: If I remember correctly, they used the Tesseract because, at this point, the Bifrost was still out of action (it wasn't repaired until sometime shortly before the beginning of *Thor: The Dark World*), which I feel is worth mentioning for context.

Comment: Wow that means there is yet another plot hole in Ragnarok. Heimdall could have just used the blue cube to transport Thor off the garbage planet the whole time. Such lazy writing with no explanations.

Comment: @Chloe How would Heimdall have got to the vault? Hela had taken over the castle.

Comment: @Chloe Thor was on Sakaar AFTER Hela took over. Heimdal would have had to break into the palace to steal the tesseract. And even then they used a device to harness the power in Avengers. There's no reason to believe he'd have access to that either.

Comment: Not to mention that Heimdall was a little busy single-handedly protecting as much of the Asgardian population from Hela as he could which is why, even during what seems to be simple communication with Thor, he had to cut it off rather quickly.

Comment: He (Heimdall) was sneaking all over Asgard. He can literally see around corners and across the universe. There is absolutely nothing stopping him from pickup up the cube and whatever other equipment he needed.

Comment: @anaximander added in answer too with Loki's quote

Answer (score 3):

Those "designs" you mentioned, are created when the "**[bifrost](https://marvel-movies.fandom.com/wiki/Bifrost_Bridge)**" or any bifrost related mechanism/tool is used for teleportation. 
The signature pattern is also noted when Thor arrives in Wakanda using the teleportation power of StormBreaker.

[image]

In the instance in question, they used the space stone instead to teleport, hence the absence of the pattern. This is supported by the absence of that pattern too in the first instance of teleportation by the space stone (Red Skull) in Captain America: The First Avenger.

[image]